# MPS error: can't find model: java.awt, java.io, etc

Tags: mps

I wanted to open the mpscmindstorms project (created with MPS 1.5) in current MPS 3.2. After opening it I get a big lot of Errors: "Can't find model: java.awt" / java.io, java.lang etc.

Where is the problem? In my project or in my MPS configuration?

Thanks, Achim

Comment: I don't think that will work. The projects deprecated and is unmaintained for years. You would have to apply all intermediate migrations vom 1.5 to 3.2 on your own. Which would basically mean opening the project with all of those MPS versions and hop everything works fine. But the good news is mpscmindstorms super seeded by [mebddr](http://mbeddr.com).

Comment: I am also not sure, whether it will work. But I can open the project. And Java.io and all of these don't exist since yesterday but for years. So I don't understand where the errors come from.
I have also installed mbeddr. Do you want to say, that I don't need everything from mpscmindstorms because of mbeddr? Which things can I omit?